# How to wait for PhantomJS' fs.write to finish writing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, file-io, phantomjs

I am developing a PhantomJS script to download all resources of a website and test them executing a bash script.

To do that, I have written the page.onResourceReceived method when I save the file using fs.write() and then I execute the bash script with execFile().

```
page.onResourceReceived = function(resource) {
    if (resource.stage == 'end') {
        fileName = getFileNameFromURL(resource.url);
        fs.write('files/' + fileName, resource.body, 'wb');
        execFile('sh', [SH_PATH, 'files/' + fileName], null, null);
    }
}
```

*(this is not the whole onResourceReceived code)*

If I configure a callback for execFile, it throws a no such file or directory error, but then, I check directory and file is there.

I think it could be a synchronization issue.

1. Is fs.write an async method?
2. Is there any alternative to synchronously execute fs.write and execFile methods?

**Update**

I have also tried this:

```
function waitForFile(filePath, attempts) {
    var fileExists = false;
    var i = 0;
    while (!fileExists && i < attempts) {
        wait(50);
        fileExists = fs.exists(filePath) && fs.isFile(filePath) && fs.size(filePath) > 0;
        i++;
    }
}

page.onResourceReceived = function(resource) {
    if (resource.stage == 'end') {
        fileName = getFileNameFromURL(resource.url);
        fs.write('files/' + fileName, resource.body, 'wb');
        waitForFile('files/' + fileName, 5);
        execFile('sh', [SH_PATH, 'files/' + fileName], null, null);
    }
}
```

Where wait() is a function that keeps the thread busy during X milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

`fs.write` method in PhantomJS [doesn't seem](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/write.html) to have callback.

Just add a little timeout to give OS time to finish writing to disk.

```
page.onResourceReceived = function(resource) {
    if (resource.stage == 'end') {
        fileName = getFileNameFromURL(resource.url);
        fs.write('files/' + fileName, resource.body, 'wb');

        setTimeout(function(){
            execFile('sh', [SH_PATH, 'files/' + fileName], null, null);
        }, 500);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but even with a delay, there are several resources that fail when executing the bash script.
I will try again with a bigger delay but I think there should be a better fix.

Comment: timeouts are not an effective way achieve sync/ordering in async calls and is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this issue is to wrap the `fs.write()` call in a function which returns a `Promise` object and proceed with the `exeFile()` call once the returned `Promise` is resolved. There are several JS libraries to help you do this explicitly. I personally use [`Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

An alternative approach is to use [*Async.js*](https://github.com/caolan/async). IMO, this helps achieve a cleaner, more readable and maintainable code/flow in several scenarios (which may include this one).

The `Promise` approach is described briefly and *Async.js* essentials are explained sufficiently for beginners [here](https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/taming-asynchronous-javascript-with-async).

Comment: Agreed, this way is definitely better in terms of readability and later extensibility. Please, provide a code sample for the OP situation using your library of choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and the links. I didn't know anything about Promises. But, what would the Promise detect to execute the callback? I mean, the fs.write() method finishes although the file doesn't actually exists. Is it possible that the callback will be called just finishing the fs.write() method, so it will lead to the same behaviour?